# Subscribe to application transition changes

Tags: flutter, dart

I need my app to react whenever the user:

- switches to another app
- returns back to the app
- tries to close the app

How can I subscribe to these changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onGenerateRoute` property on the `MaterialApp` to listen and execute your methods each time a named route is made ( when you navigate over pages in your pages) :

```
    MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          print("navigated to new route")
        },
    //...
```

You can use `WillPopScope` widget to listen for the navigator's `pop()` method which goes back to the previous screen if it exists in the stack route, and close the app when it's the only one left in the stack route.

```
WillPopScope(
 onWillPop: () async {
  print("route popped");
  return Future.value(true);
},      child: WillPopScope(
onWillPop: () async {
  print("route popped");
  return Future.value(true); // will allow popping, if the value is false, it will not pop.
},
child: Scaffold(//...)
```

if you're willing to use a custom personalized `Navigator` in your app, then you can set from it the `onGeneratedRoute` and also the `onPopPage` which let you listen to `pop()` over the sub-tree it takes:

```
Navigator(
onPopPage: /*...*/,
onGenerateRoute: /*...*/,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can do, is to use life cycle methods to execute a piece of code whenever a widget screen is rendered ( `initState()` will run), and when you `pop()` it, it will be disposed ( `dispose()` will execute ), but it requires using `StatefulWidget`:

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- when switch to another app as well as return to the app You can use
**WidgetsBindingObserver** in your widgets and listen to **AppLifecycleState**.

2- in order to handle resume callback

```
Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (resumeCallBack != null) {
          await resumeCallBack();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        if (suspendingCallBack != null) {
          await suspendingCallBack();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
```

3- to perform some function on app close try to use **willpopscope**